# Magento 2 : Banner Image Was Not Comes When I Edit the Grid

Tags: magento2

I have Create New Grid View For Upload Banner From Back-end Side .

The Upload Image Was Save Success Fully In Data Base .

But When I Edit That The All Other Information Was Edit But The Image File Path Are Not Come So That Can Not Edit .

If We Choose The New Image Than The New Image Was Save But Existing Image Was Not Save When We Edit That Grid In Magento2.

That'd My Save.php File

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(Action\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();


    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Banner');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            $model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }

        try{
            $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                ['fileId' => 'banner']
            );
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
            $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner_banner'));
                if($result['error']==0)
                {
                    $data['banner'] = 'banner_banner' . $result['file'];
                }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //unset($data['image']);
        }
          // if(isset($data['banner']) || $data['banner']){
         //                $data['banner'] = implode(',',$data['banner']);
         //            }

        if(isset($data['banner']['delete']) && $data['banner']['delete'] == '1')
            $data['banner'] = '';




        if(isset($data['store_id']) && $data['store_id']){
            $data['store_id'] = implode(',',$data['store_id']);
        }
        //           
        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

}

And That's My Edit.php File

namespace Vrinsoft\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\banner;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 */
public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Init actions
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
protected function _initAction()
{
    // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vrinsoft_Banner::Banner')
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Vrinsoft Banner'), __('Vrinsoft Banner'))
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Item'), __('Manage Item'));
    return $resultPage;
}

/**
 * Edit Item
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{

    // 1. Get ID and create model
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    // echo $id; exit;
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Banner');
    // echo json_encode($model->getData());exit;
    // 2. Initial checking
    if ($id) {


        $model->load($id);
         // if(isset($data['banner']) || $data['banner']){
         //                $data['banner'] = implode(',',$data['banner']);
         //            }
        if (!$model->getId()) {

            $this->messageManager->addError(__('This item no longer exists.'));
            /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }

    // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
    $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);

    if (!empty($data)) {  

        $model->setData($data);
    }

    // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('banner', $model);

    // 5. Build edit form
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_initAction();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vrinsoft_Banner::banner');
    $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Vrinsoft'), __('Vrinsoft'));
    $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(
        $id ? __('Edit Banner') : __('New Banner'),
        $id ? __('Edit Banner') : __('New Banner')
    );
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($id ? __('Edit Banner') : __('New Banner'));
    // $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New Item'));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Solution Is Add The Below Code On Following File Path

> /app/code/Your_Extention/Your_Module/Controller/Adminhtml/banner/Save.php

In That File Add Below Code

```
if(is_array($data['image']))
 {
    echo $str_val = implode("", $data['image']);
    $data['image'] = $str_val;
 }
```

Here The Multiple Image The Have Considere The Image Array So We Have Convert That Array To String Using Simple impload Function.